# workflow person field into a text field returns 2

Tags: workflow

I am trying to put the person name of a person field into a text field
with a workflow.

So, when a new item is added to a list, the workflow should copy the name into a field.

The work flow completes succefully but in my text field I get number 2 instead of the person name.

Do you know what could be wrong?

Note: the list a calendar connected to Outlook. The new item is created by Outlook. From Sharepoint it works fine.

Comment: Can you please tell us what's there in the "created by" field for the event added through outlook.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the "LOOKUP VALUE" of the person field. Each person field is really a lookup column to the user information list of the site collection. Your number is the ID of the lookup. You need to return the field as something other than string.

http://www.sharepointprogrammer.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/lookupperson.png

Comment: I don't have that lookup value. I only have, string, visualized name, access name, email user  number id. I'm on a 2010 workflow. Could it be the reason?

Comment: Then you need to use the "Name" not the string...

Comment: I did it actually. It returns 2, as I wrote. But only if the workflow is started inserting the calendar event from Outlook.

Comment: Can you show your workflow logic?

Comment: Well, I have tried to put the workflow in a different way and works. Sorry, for the trouble